# When are tunneling and bubbling events useful in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, event-bubbling, mousedown

I understand how bubbling and tunneling works. However, i'm confused about using them.
Here is why:

I want to handle a mouse click event. To bubble it, there is `MouseDown` and, to tunnel it, there is `PreviewMouseDown`. However, `MouseDown` doesn't necessarily mean the user clicked the control. May be the user pressed the button and moved away from it to cancel the click.
I wouldn't want to change anything if the button is not being clicked.

So my question is, how are the Bubbling/Tunneling strategies useful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the event is listed `RoutedEventArgs`, then it's routed event. Routed events support a RoutingStrategy of Bubble, Tunnel, or Direct. Let's take a look at the event handler of `Button.Click`:

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Button Test clicked!");
}
```

There specified `RoutedEventArgs`, so it's routed event. Because the *preview* were not specified in the name, therefore this Bubble event. This can be demonstrated in the following way:

```
<Grid ButtonBase.Click="Grid_Click">
    <Button Name="TestButton" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Test" />
</Grid>
```

When you click on the `TestButton`, the event is to rise above the `Grid`, and displays a message:

> Button Test clicked!

**`Usefulness of Bubbling/Tunneling strategies`**

*`Tunneling`*

Many of the standard controls listen to events, such as `KeyDown`, `MouseDown`, etc. For example -`DataGrid` control. I want by pressing the enter key the function was called adding a record. But `DataGrid` already has `KeyDown` event, so the event is not raised. So you have to do your logic in the Tunnel event - `PreviewKeyDown`, it will work before the `KeyDown` event. The same applies to `RichTextBoxControl`.

*`Bubbling`*

Sometimes, you need a global handler for a specific event, so it worked for all controls in VisualTree. Naturally, the a direct event you can not do it. Hence on the stage comes Bubbling event.

Another reason is the ideology of the WPF. This `Button` can contain anything: `Image`, another `Button`, etc:

[image]

The user can click on the `TextBlock/Image` in the `Button`. How do we know that the click was in `Button`? That's right, with the help of Bubbling event.

For more information, please see:

[Understanding Routed Events and Commands In WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx)

`Edit`

I changed little bit a `Click` handler:

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String message = "#" + eventCounter.ToString() + ":\r\n" +
            " Sender: " + sender.ToString() + ":\r\n" +
            " Source: " + e.Source + ":\r\n" +
            " Original Source: " + e.OriginalSource;

    lstEvents.Items.Add(message);
}
```

Result of click on the `Button`:

[image]

Comment: But, as far as i know, Click is a direct event rather than Bubbling event.

Comment: @SanSolo: If it was direct, then message `Button Test clicked!` did not appear. We set a handler for the `Grid`, not to the `Button`, and a click on the `Button`, the event worked for the `Grid`. The event at the `Button` moved up, and came to the `Grid`. Direct click event, as far as I know, has been in *`WinForms`*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I ran the example you provided to check Sender,Source and original Source. Thw values were Grid, Button and Button:Test respectively. So by default, all WPF events are bubbling events? This is confusing...tunneling events have preview keyword, but don't know which are bubbling events.

Comment: @SanSolo: By default, all events are `RoutedEvents`. True, if the name is in *`preview`*, it Tunnel event. You can view the article I gave you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I found this on [another msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx): >he event route can travel in one of two directions depending on the event definition, but generally the route travels from the source element and then "bubbles" upward through the element tree until it reaches the element tree root (typically a page or a window).                So, default strategy is bubbling.

Answer (score 4):

Hi though you can get some good articles regading this on net but still I will try to answer this.

> Suppose you give a button a very plain appearance consisting of a single Rectangle, and provide a simple piece of text as the content Even with such basic visuals, there are still two elements present: the text and the rectangle.The button should respond to a mouse click whether the mouse is over the text or the rectangle. In the standard .NET event handling model, this would mean registering a **MouseLeftButtonUp event handler for both elements.**
>
> > This problem would get much worse when taking advantage of WPF’s content
> >     model. A Button is not restricted to having plain text as a caption—it can contain any
> >     object as content. The xaml below is not especially ambitious, but even
> >     this has six visible elements: the yellow outlined circle, the two dots for the eyes, the
> >     curve for the mouth, the text, and the button background itself. **Attaching event
> >     handlers for every single element would be tedious and inefficient.** To work MouseDown We would have to add 8 MouseDownEvents to this bit of code.

```
<Button PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDownButton" MouseDown="MouseDownButton">
        <Grid PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDownGrid" MouseDown="MouseDownGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Canvas PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDownCanvas" MouseDown="MouseDownCanvas" Width="20" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Ellipse PreviewMouseDown="PreviewMouseDownEllipse" MouseDown="MouseDownEllipse" x:Name="myEllipse" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="1" Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Yellow" Stroke="Black" />
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="4.5" Canvas.Top="5" Width="2.5" MouseDown="MouseDownEllipse" Height="3" Fill="Black" />
                <Ellipse Canvas.Left="11" Canvas.Top="5" Width="2.5" MouseDown="MouseDownEllipse" Height="3" Fill="Black" />
                <Path Data="M 5,10 A 3,3 0 0 0 13,10" Stroke="Black" MouseDown="Path_MouseDown_1"/>
            </Canvas>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown_1">Click!</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

> > WPF uses RoutedEvents **Bubble/Tunnel /Normal**, which are rather more thorough than normal events. Instead
> >     of just calling handlers attached to the element that raised the event, WPF walks the
> >     tree of user interface elements, calling all handlers for the routed event attached to
> >     any node from the originating element right up to the root of the user interface tree.

Comment: That answer clarifies the need for Bubbling/Tunneling, which is the title of my question. However, i'm still confused about why we would use MouseUp or MouseDown given that it is a not a conclusive action like Click. MousewheelUp/Down i can see scenarios where it is useful.But in case of MouseUp, we change something, user moves away from the button, there is no click...where would we use it?

Answer (score 1):

As you said you know the concept of bubbling/tunneling so not going into that. But this is what these events are intended for i.e they let you know if the Mouse button was Down or Up on the control or its children.Events are working fine.For your scenario you should use the `Click` event of your button which tell if the mouse was down and up on the button itself.

Thanks

Comment: Click would be a direct event. my confusion is regarding the use of bubbling/tunneling events